# Use of DI register in String operations

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I was looking at the Compiler output for a C program, just for academic purposes and happened to get the following output.

```
 .file   "test.c"
 .section        .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello World"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
    .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I understand the parts where the based pointer and stack pointer operations are taking place and other operation, I wanted to know what is  the use of putting

```
movl    $.LC0, %edi
```

how is loading the address of the test "Hello world" from the data block into the destination register solving the purpose, we could have just loaded that address in the accumulator and let **printf** handle it. I am not used to programming in assembly but i can make out what the program is doing, am i missing something obvious here?
Google searches showed that they were used for string operations but none said why?

Comment: The compiler can pass parameters to a function through registers instead of the stack. movl    $.LC0, %edi is the parameter to the printf function.

Comment: I have understood that the edi is being used to pass a parameter, but my question is as to why that specific register, why not accumulator or stack?

Comment: That is defined by the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) of the architecture, namely the [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your call on `printf` may be passing arguments by registers and not by stack because it was optimised in that way, or because its attributes during compilation were set to `__fastcall` (MSVC) or `__attribute__((fastcall))`.

`%esi` and `%esi` registers are used in string operations because of their meaning to string instructions, such as `cmps`, `lods`, `movs`, `scas`, `stos`, `outs` or `ins`. These instructions use the destination and source register for quick sequential access to a string of bytes/words/doublewords. They can be used in loops to make simple operations that are known to be performed continuously in memory, and can shorter execution time in combination with loop prefixes by removing the need of pointer manipulation and limit checking.

A very good example on this is the `movs` instruction (it also has another forms as `movsb`, `movsw`, `movsd`). If you wanted to write a simple string copy procedure without string instruction, you write something like this:

```
; IN: EAX=source&, EBX=dest&, ECX=count
; OUT: nothing
copy:
    .loop:
        cmp ecx, 0
        jz .end

        dec ecx
        mov al, byte [eax+ecx]
        mov byte [ebx+ecx], al
        jmp .loop
    .end:
    ret
```

`movsb` instruction copies `[esi]` to `[edi]`, increments `esi` and `edi`, then decrements `ecx`. With this in mind you can write somethign similar to this:

```
; IN: ESI=source&, EDI=dest&, ECX=count
; OUT: nothing
copy:
    .loop:
        jecxz .end
        movsb

        jmp .loop
    .end:
    ret
```

Using loop prefixes, you can again speed the whole operation

```
; IN: ESI=source&, EDI=dest&, ECX=count
; OUT: nothing
copy:
    rep movsb
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to say yes and no to user35443 answer.

> I wanted to know what is the use of putting
>
> ```
> movl    $.LC0, %edi
> ```

Since you are using 64bit Linux (from the use of `rbp`), in 64 bit land, parameters are passed in registers.  `rdi` contains the first parameter, `rsi` the second, `rdx` 3rd, `rcx` 4th, `r8` 5th, `r9` the 6th parameter; any more parameters are passed on the stack.

> we could have just loaded that address in the accumulator and let
>   printf handle it

No!  When using Assembly, it is up to you to read and understand the ABI for the OS you are using and follow it to the T!  If you were using Windows, the first parameter would be in `rcx` instead.  It has nothing to do with the source nor destination.

the "Accumulator" is actually a parameter to `printf` and all vararg functions really.  `r/eax` contains the number of floating point numbers passed in the `xmm` registers, since in your example code no floats are passed, `eax` is set to 0.